# Asp.net WebService function doesn't return JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, web-services

I've read every post about this issue, but nothing solved the problem.
I'll be glad if someone can help me with that.

There's an MVC3 project with a web service that I added.
I have only one function called Test, and when I call it through an HTTP GET method (regular url) , it returns the data with XML format instead of JSON.
How can I make it return JSON?

The web service:

```
namespace TestServer
{
    [WebService]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class TestWebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {  
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public List<string> Test()
        {    
            return new List<string>
                {
                    {"Test1"},
                    {"Test2"}
                };                    
        }
    }
}
```

The web.config (only relevant parts):

```
<configuration>
  <location path="TestWebservice.asmx">
    <system.web>
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </location>  
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <clear/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx"
        type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
        validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The url:

```
http://localhost:49740/testwebservice.asmx/Test
```

The result (which is not what I want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>Test1</string>
  <string>Test2</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I'll be glad if someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the content type HTTP header to `application/json` when sending the request. For example if you are using jQuery AJAX you could do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/testwebservice.asmx/Test',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d[0]);
    }
});
```

Also you need to enable the GET verb on your `[ScriptMethod]` attribute:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
[WebMethod]
public List<string> Test()
{
    return new List<string>
    {
        {"Test1"},
        {"Test2"}
    };
}
```

You could also get rid of everything you put in your `web.config` about this service. It's not necessary.

Oh and by the way, classic ASMX web services is an obsolete technology. You should use more recent technologies such as ASP.NET MVC controller actions returning JSON, WCF, or even the bleeding edge ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API.

Comment: Oh ok so now I understand the problem. I really just tried to open the url through my browser. The actual use is from iOS, so I'll need to find a way to specify the request type header in the code.

By the way, if I choose to use the MVC 4 Web API, I'm afraid that I won't be able to find hosting sites that support it. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right, because you could always do a bin deployment. You don't need the hosting site to support anything. As long as it supports ASP.NET 4.0 you could host it without any problems.

Comment: Got it. So I'll use the new web api. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The REST service serialize the data in particular format(XML, JSON) based upon the [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header send from the client. It is the `Accept` header that says to the service which formats the client can accept.

When you trying to access the service directly from the browser URL the value of the `Accept` header is set to some default value as below (in firefox)

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

The above header explicitly says that I can accept html, xhtml or xml. Since the `application/xml` format is explicitly specified but not `application/json` the REST service returns the data in xml format. (I don't understand what is the use of `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json` though).

So if you want to make the service return JSON data you have to specify the accept header the corresponding format. If you are using jQuery you can utilize the `$.getJSON()` that will set the accept header as `"application/json"` or you can even use `$.ajax` with `dataType` as `json`.

http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/returning_json_from_wcfwebapi

Comment: Great. thanks for explaining about the header. I will find a way to specify it in the code of the iOS app. Also you gave a useful link - now I understand that I need to build the web service as a WCF.

Comment: @Edi In the link I shared the service is created using WCF Web API. Now they have merged that into ASP.NET Web API. So if you are going to create a REST service then better you have to check with http://www.asp.net/web-api.

Comment: Cool! The tutorial on the link that you gave is exactly what I was looking for! Just a little question - do hosting sites support the new technology?